# Unable to create a directory as managed in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to create a directory as managed in cygwin.
    For this i was using 
    **mount -o managed c:/cygwin/usr/src/kernel /usr/src/kernel**
    But after running this command it is giving below error

```
mount: invalid option - 'managed'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such option `managed` in Cygwin's `mount` command.  `man mount` will show you all the options available.

Comment: Thanks pak, I am trying to cross compile linux on cygwin, following below link https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2007-08/msg00101.html .  Step 5 is mentioned to mount as managed. In man page we cannot see this, managed is a mount point under -o option