# Unable to mount a driectory as managed in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to mount a directory as **managed** in cygwin.
    For this i was using 
    **mount -o managed c:/cygwin/usr/src/kernel /usr/src/kernel**
    But after running this command it is giving below error

```
mount: invalid option - 'managed'
Do i need to add this managed mount option / it is my default present
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create a driectory as managed in cygwin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164215/unable-to-create-a-driectory-as-managed-in-cygwin)